# Angular.js, form validation only on submit

Tags: angularjs

How to do form validation with Angular.js only on submit?

I want to show error messages only on submit, like on this page: http://live.com/ with ignoring focus changing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UI5qOxKEwfvOGh26NhKx?p=preview).

The forms model will always contain actual information about its validity, so you can just check it on submit.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a variable that is set to false at rendering time and would be set to true on click of the submit button.

Something similar to this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Lt4JmAPWBrRfO3fTIlS?p=preview)

Comment: I like this sample, but it's not what I need. After clicking on submit button, I can edit text fields and messages will show or hide. I need to show messages only after clicking on submit button and don't update them.